# Microsoft Graph API Get callRecord method: version of callRecord

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have subscription to new callRecords in Teams and it works fine, but sometimes when I call "Get callRecord" Graph API method to get details of Teams call and there is no organizer's session info. I looked later and there is organizer's session info. I also see "version" property in callRecord.

Is there a way to surely new that it is last version of callRecord and it will not be changed later? I need to know if user was in the meeting or not, but this thing with version give me uncertainty.

Code is just for example:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#communications/callRecords(sessions())/$entity",
    "id": "5da1894e-5af4-47f9-a304-e26208c5469f",
    //I talk about this attribute
    "version": 3,
    "type": "groupCall",
    "modalities": [
        "audio",
        "videoBasedScreenSharing",
        "screenSharing"
    ],
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-12-09T14:01:42.0108662Z",
    "startDateTime": "2020-12-09T10:48:24.8299343Z",
    "endDateTime": "2020-12-09T13:22:10.515688Z",
    "joinWebUrl": "...",
    "organizer": {
        "acsUser": null,
        "spoolUser": null,
        "phone": null,
        "guest": null,
        "encrypted": null,
        "onPremises": null,
        "acsApplicationInstance": null,
        "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
        "applicationInstance": null,
        "application": null,
        "device": null,
        "user": {
            "id": "c2408055-2c55-489f-b8f5-5f404dbab627",
            "displayName": "...",
            "tenantId": "..."
        }
    },
    "participants": [...],
    "sessions@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#communications/callRecords('5da1894e-5af4-47f9-a304-e26208c5469f')/sessions",
    "sessions": [...]
}
```

Comment: If you look at the version property, it means the higher version call records with the same id includes additional data compared to the lower version. Once a new record is available the version number moves up.

Comment: @Dev is correct, version changes based on the number of call records available, Once a version of existing call increased you can distinguish between both call records using version number, to retain the same version is not what call records api provides, it automatically increases the version

Comment: Yes, thank you for comments, but still I don't know when I get the last version of call record, which will not be changed later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222811/microsoft-graph-api-get-callrecord-method-version-of-callrecord/66418519#comment115454640_65222811) by [Trinetra-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11560663/trinetra-msft) says:

> Version changes based on the number of call records available, once a
> version of existing call increased you can distinguish between both
> call records using version number, to retain the same version is not
> what call records API provides, it automatically increases the
> version.

It is not possible to get the last version of the call record.