# What is exactly Teams CallRecord version field meaning

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I've set up receiving of Teams CallRecords into Splunk and now stuck in a process of understanding them. I thought that one CallRecord represents one unique Teams call (like Mr. A dialed Mr. B, Mr. B answered, they talked and eventually hung up - that's a CallRecord) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-callrecord?view=graph-rest-1.0) suggests that it is so: *"callRecord resource type represents a single peer-to-peer call or a group call between multiple participants",* *"id - String - Unique identifier for the call record. Read-only."*

But what I see is many CallRecords with same id but different versions ("version" field). These records might have different DateTimes of start and end, different lastModifiedDateTime, some versions have null values of organizer* and participant* fields. I saw quantity of versions from 1 to 66.

So here are my questions:

1. Does the one CallRecord represent one unique conversation? If yes, what would be it's unique identificator? id+version? Then why there are records with same id, different versions and same other data except lastModifiedFateTime (so these records are roughly the same and it will result in double accounting in final report)? And why there are records with null fields of organizer*?
2. Does the set of all CallRecords with same id and different versions represent one call? If I merge all such records into one I get multivalue fields of startDateTime, endDateTime and other DateTimes - which values of them I need to use for accounting - min(startDateTime) and max(endDateTime) or what?
3. Maybe there is some deep dive Microsoft documentation on this versioning? Frankly, I've completely lost here.

Comment: Hi @english-voodoo, Could you please share info about which version you are mentioning either call or team version and meanwhile can you go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) for an overview of call recordings.

Comment: @Ravindra-MSFT, thanks for your input. I'm talking about CallRecord field "version". As of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-callrecord?view=graph-rest-1.0), it is "Monotonically increasing version of the call record. Higher version call records with the same id includes additional data compared to the lower version.".

And thanks for the link to document. Unfortunately, there are no answers to my questions.

Comment: If you look at the version property, it means the higher version call records with the same id includes additional data compared to the lower version. Once a new record is available the version number moves up. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222811/microsoft-graph-api-get-callrecord-method-version-of-callrecord